# path to php file on server not working is this correct

Tags: php, axios

myscript.php file located on a server at namecheap

www.mysite.com/scriptfolder/myscript.php

if Im making an axios post to it from my firstComp.js,

so I have in my directory

```
index.html
scriptfolder/myscript.php
js/components/firstComp.js
```

I tried several different variations, is this the correct path? as I need to troubleshoot if this is not the issue.

On my firstComp.js

```
axios.post('../scriptfolder/myscript.php',
```

What is wierd is..
if i hardcode it and use CORS on chrome, it dose not return any data.

```
http://mysite(.com)/scriptfolder/myscript.php
```

if I use another of my domains and host the script there and use cors it DOES return data

making the axios call from mysite(.com)

```
http://anotherSite(.com)/scriptfolder/myscript.php
```

Comment: Try `axios.post('/scriptfolder/myscript.php',`

Comment: I am not getting the error not found with that, however i updated the op...as Im scratching my head for the past 4 hours on this

Comment: I don't understand your reply...